# Pingfederate SCIM Inbound provisioning

Tags: ping, pingfederate, scim

I have configured SCIM inbound provisioning in pingfederate 7.2.0 using Active Directory as an user store. But when I hit the URL exposed by ping to search for an user I get the following error on the browser-

```
{    "totalResults":0,"itemsPerPage":0,"startIndex":0,
    "errors":[{"description":"User and/or certificate not found","code":"401"}]
}
```

In the logs it says

```
11:34:29,251 DEBUG [Authenticator] AuthnInfo: ID='null' cert:false 
basic:false from CERT:'null' BASIC:'null' 11:34:29,251 ERROR [UsersIdResource] 
Unable to find a connection associated with the username/password and/or 
certificate passed in with the request.
11:34:29,252 DEBUG [TrackingIdSupport] [cross-reference-message] 
entityid:null subject:ranajoy
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Are you providing SCIM client authentication credentials in your request? This is a requirement per the Ping docs. The server error indicates that credentials are missing. Maybe you can update your question with the request you are making to PF?

Comment: https://localhost.localdomain.com:9031/pf-scim/v1/Users/ranajoy   This is the url I am hitting from the browser. I have configured pingfeferate to use basic authentication for inbound provisioning. I am providing the username and the password while making the request. Still no luck

Comment: If I had to guess, the HTTP Authorization header for Basic HTTP authentication isn't properly formed in your request.  I'd suggest you open a ticket with our support team to diagnose it further: https://ping.force.com/Support

Comment: I tried that. But then it couldn't log me on with my ping identity credentials to salesforce giving some SAML error page. :P So I came here.

Comment: We're reaching out to you via your twitter post to get support helping you. May be best to close this question from SO.

Comment: Just email us at support@pingidentity.com.

Comment: Thanks Ian for pointing out the meaning of the log entries. I developed a java rest client to test the urls and its working fine. Facing an issue with outbound provisioning. Will discuss that in a separate thread

Answer (score 0):

I was having this exact same issue. I set up my Provisioning connection correctly, and it worked in other environments, and everything looked good. But then I got this error. If I changed the Basic Auth to a bad password, the error message at least changed to `"Bad Password for <user>"`.

I took another look at my connection and realized I never actually activated the connection:

[image: Active radio box checked in connection properties]